# Try/Catch not work on T-SQL stored procedure (not rollback transaction)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions, try-catch

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MYSTOREDPROCEDURENAME]
AS
BEGIN   

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Temp](
        Col1 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        Col2 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        Col3 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        Col4 smallint NULL)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Temp]([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4])
    SELECT [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]

    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 )
    SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, ISNULL((SELECT Col4 FROM [dbo].[#Temp] WHERE [dbo].[#Temp].[Col1]=MyTable2.Field1 AND [dbo].[#Temp].[Col2]=MyTable2.Field2 AND [dbo].[#Temp].[Col3]=MyTable2.Field3),1) AS Espr1
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable2]

    DROP TABLE [dbo].[#Temp]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
          ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
          ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
          ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
          ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
          ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

If I execute this sp, this error message is displayed:

*Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure MYSTOREDPROCEDURENAME, Line 32
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure MYSTOREDPROCEDURENAME, Line 32
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.*

Now, beyond the error, I do not understand why the block "catch" isn't reached and the transaction rollback is not done (after error "MyTable" is locked!)

Where am I wrong? Why "catch" block does not work?

P.S. The stored procedure was performed on Sql Server 2005

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but try/catch only works with transactions started inside, not outside of `try` section. So you can move both `begin` and `commit` into the `try` part, and the `catch` part will still have the `rollback`.

Besides, some errors are not caught by try/catch, such as deferred names resolution errors. This is by design.

**UPD:** Ah, I see. Here is the answer: [Issues with T-SQL TRY CATCH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018555/issues-with-t-sql-try-catch)

As it appears, SQL Server considers collation conflict as severe as the deferred name resolution failure. This particular error cannot be caught by the try/catch in the same module where it happened.

P.S. The last time I ever encountered this error was on MSSQL 2000, in which try/catch was not introduced yet, so I didn't know it isn't handled. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: I put the "BEGIN TRANSACTION" out "begin try" why I referred to the example shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx; in any case, I write it in but I've the exact same behavior

Answer (score 0):

The reason you try block isnt reached is because long before any code is executed it is parsed and validated. This fails so nothing is executed.

There are 2 errors in your code that prevent it from ever running, the first is a collation error. You should really look into that more thoroughly how that happens within 1 database and fix the underlying cause but for now you can use COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS on the offending column.

The second error is exactly what Ennor said, you have a transaction around you try/catch. that is not how this works. for the example you can simply remove the BEGIN/COMMIT entirely as they don't really do anything anyway.

Here is a fully functional sample that I just ran in a generic sql server database with default option named [demo].

```
use demo
go

create table [MyTable] (
    Col1 varchar(50) not null
    , Col2 varchar(50) not null
    , Col3 varchar(50) not null
    , Col4 smallint null
    )

insert MyTable
values (
    'some string'
    , 'some string'
    , 'some string'
    , 1
    )

create table [MyTable2] (
    Col1 varchar(50) not null
    , Col2 varchar(50) not null
    , Col3 varchar(50) not null
    , Col4 smallint null
    )
go

create procedure [dbo].[my_proc]
as
begin
begin try
begin transaction
    create table #Temp (
        Col1 varchar(50) not null
        , Col2 varchar(50) not null
        , Col3 varchar(50) not null
        , Col4 smallint null
        )

    insert into #Temp (
        [Col1]
        , [Col2]
        , [Col3]
        , [Col4]
        )
    select [Col1]
        , [Col2]
        , [Col3]
        , [Col4]
    from [dbo].[MyTable]

    truncate table [dbo].[MyTable]

    insert into [dbo].[MyTable] (
        Col1
        , Col2
        , Col3
        , Col4
        )
    select [Col1]
        , [Col2]
        , [Col3]
        , ISNULL((
                select Col4
                from #Temp
                where #Temp.[Col1] = MyTable2.[Col1]
                    and #Temp.[Col2] = MyTable2.[Col2]
                    and #Temp.[Col3] = MyTable2.[Col3]
                ), 1) as Espr1
    from [dbo].[MyTable2]

    drop table #Temp
    if @@TRANCOUNT <> 0
    commit transaction
end try

    begin catch
        select ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber
            , ERROR_SEVERITY() as ErrorSeverity
            , ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState
            , ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure
            , ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine
            , ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;

        if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            rollback transaction;
    end catch;
end

exec my_proc
```

Comment: I tried to remove the "begin transaction" before the "begin try" (as in the example), but in this way, in case of error, MyTable is empty (because of truncate) while it should not

Comment: @LukePet in that case you will have to give a more comprehensive explanation of what you expect the code to do.

Comment: I simply would like that all the instructions included in "begin try" block were performed as "atomic" (ie transaction) and, in case of an error, it returns to its initial state.

Comment: I added the transaction to inside the try, this now works as you describe and only throws to catch when a different error comes up.