# SQL Job with TRY reports success on failure when inserting from remote SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, try-catch, sql-server-2000

I've found a way to fail a SQL Scheduled Job (with severity 16) that does not report failure (and so does not send email notifications). I've fixed my immediate issue, but I want to know why there is a failure case that does not report as failure, and if there are any other surprising ways to miss notification.

I've set up two linked servers and am attempting to run an hourly scheduled SQL Job on one that queries the other. I found this morning that **the code in the SP had not been running, but the history on the Job was reporting success**. The Job's only step is `EXEC _testSP`. If I ran `EXEC _testSP` in a query window from SSMS, I received this error message:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

The SP's contents are wrapped in `TRY ... CATCH`. If I remove the `TRY ... CATCH`, executing the SP gives up this error message:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

This made sense. The remote table was referenced with a `SELECT * FROM` and some columns had been added to it. I've removed the asterix and the job runs fine now, but I want to make sure that *all* future exceptions get logged either by the job failure notification, or the `CATCH` block in `_testSP`. I don't understand why this one didn't get logged, and I hope that someone can explain it to me.

The job runs and fails and notifies just as I would expect when the `TRY ... CATCH` wrapping is removed, but we have some important things in the `TRY ... CATCH` that need to be kept.

This is not a duplicate of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018555/issues-with-t-sql-try-catch). The [Microsoft BOL for `TRY...CATCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) says that some exceptions cannot be caught by `TRY...CATCH`. It may be related, but what I've found is an exception that is not caught by the *Scheduled Job agent*.

**Reproduceable example:** (also try removing the `TRY...CATCH` wrapper and see the change)

```
USE [RemoteServer].[Database]
CREATE TABLE [Tally](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID2] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [LocalServer]
-- Setup procedure
    CREATE PROCEDURE _testSP
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        BEGIN TRY

        -- Create destination temp table
            CREATE TABLE #tempb (a int)

        -- Insert into temp table from remote Tally table
            DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
            SELECT @query = '
                SELECT TOP 5 *
                FROM [Database].[dbo].Tally
            '
            INSERT INTO #tempb
            EXEC [RemoteServer].[master].[dbo].sp_executesql @query

        END TRY BEGIN CATCH
            -- Log the exception
            -- ...

            -- Rethrow the exception
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max), @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int;
            SELECT
                @ErrorMessage = 'Handled Exception: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(5)),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        END CATCH

    END
    GO

-- Setup job
    DECLARE @database varchar(100)
    SELECT @database = DB_Name()
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
        @job_name = '_testSPJob'
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
        @job_name = '_testSPJob',
        @step_name = '_testSPJob',
        @subsystem = N'TSQL',
        @command = 'EXEC _testSP',
        @database_name = @database
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
        @job_name =  '_testSPJob',
        @server_name = @@SERVERNAME
    GO

-- Manual execution fails
    EXEC _testSP
    GO

-- Run job
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job
        @job_name = '_testSPJob'
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
    GO

-- Select job history
    SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    WHERE step_name = '_testSPJob'
    ORDER BY run_date, run_time
    GO
```

I really need to convince the bosses to get off SQL 2000. Here are my software versions. Perhaps this is fixed in later versions of SQL?

```
SSMS Version: 2012 (11.0.5058.0)
Local DB: SQL 2005 (9.0.5069)
Remote DB: SQL 2000 (8.0.760)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is happening is correct, because you're handdling an exception, so the job is not failling. A solution could be a log so when the exception y catch you insert a row with the error description.

Comment: I am handling the exception, yes, but I am both logging it (and it's not appearing in my log) and re-throwing it (and the job still finished with success).

Comment: How are you logging it? it's in the begin catch and insert to your log table? If you surround the code with the try cath the job will be executed correctly all the time. Try also using the @@error on the catch. Or just don't use the try catch.

Comment: The exception generated by running the code in my example is a type of exception that skips `CATCH` blocks (See the above link to the Microsoft BOL). Because of this, my logging never runs, and I'm left with relying on the job failure notification to communicate the exception to me. I don't think the logging implementation is relevant to the question, which is why I took it out. Since you ask, my logging is `BEGIN TRY EXEC spLog END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH`, and is placed inside the catch block where the `...` is in my example.