# How to automatically rollback all “batches” in a (SSMS) SQL script that fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, ssms

I have SQL scripts that will be executed via the SQL Server Management Studio on a SQL Server 2012 database. The scripts are divided into a number of batches using the `GO` statement. If any update in any batch goes wrong I would like everything to be rolled backed.

I have tried to use `XACT_ABORT ON`, but it did not work as I expected:

```
begin transaction txn
go
set xact_abort on
go
insert into Table1 (Col1) values (1)
go
insert into Table1 (Col1) values (2/0)
go
insert into Table1 (Col1) values (3)
go
create procedure Proc1
as
 begin
    select * from Table1
 end
go
commit transaction txn
go
```

When running this script, insert #2 fails and insert #1 is rolled back. However, insert #3 is successful and the stored procedure is created.

Is there a way to make it so that all inserts fails if one fails?

Please note that my actual script potentially could contain hundreds of batches with hundreds of different kinds of updates (insert, update, alter, drop etc.) within some. I would thus prefer not having to add any additional code to the batches, i.e. I would like to wrap them all in one big transaction.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: GO is the default batch terminator. The way you have this coded you will orphan your transaction. Take out all those batch terminators and use try catch.

Comment: Sean, I'm affraid I need batches. I have stuff that cannot be executed together, e.g. inserts mixed with create procedure.

Comment: Well you didn't mention any of that in your post. You had three insert statements. I would still do this using try/catch. You just have to build your catch robust enough to drop objects that need to be.

Comment: Sorry, Sean, my bad. I tried to mention it in the second to last paragraph, but I totally agree that it was not clear.

Comment: I would say that you have the two options. I agree with Sean you should use try/catch whenever you can. But if you need to rollback also schema changes, and you must use GO, then you need to check @@Error :(

Comment: One way you can deal with this is to put your ddl statements in dynamic sql. It isn't great but it would work. As long as you don't have tons of ddl it isn't too bad. Then you can use the try/catch like I posted.

Comment: I hear what you are saying. As I don’t think it is practical to use try/catch in our case (the script is kind of a collection of smaller parts possibly written by different people and I don’t have the time or knowledge to edit each part). So, I’ll guess we’ll stick to our current solution that kinda works. We take a backup before running the script and if something goes wrong we use it to rollback everything :). Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: Sounds to me that you need to have your developers write better code. Any ddl statement should have checks and such so that they can be run multiple times. Taking a backup and restoring sounds like a scary approach especially in a live system.

Comment: The script is basically only used once in each of 3-5 different environments. It is handed over to another part that executes it. This other part cannot handle any errors, hence the backup/restore solution. At the same time, we have limited possibilities to test the script on beforehand as we don’t have any “local” databases that we can be sure look exactly like the targets...

Comment: With a big, wrapping transaction we would have been able to simply ask for a re-run after adjusting the script. Now we need to wait for the restore before we can do that and due to some bureaucracy involved with restores the process takes some time. Annoying, but acceptable, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it, it's not going to be as simple as you think but it works for me.

One of the first things I do in my script is this:

```
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
```

Then do your insert/updates. After every operation do this:

```
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK;END
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 BEGIN INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error) VALUES (1); BEGIN TRANSACTION;END
GO
```

And at the very end of your script add this:

```
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
```

Applying all this to the script you are trying to run will be something like this:

```
-- this on top 
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

insert into Table1 (Col1) values (1)
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK;END
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 BEGIN INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error) VALUES (1); BEGIN TRANSACTION;END
GO

insert into Table1 (Col1) values (2/0)
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK;END
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 BEGIN INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error) VALUES (1); BEGIN TRANSACTION;END
GO

insert into Table1 (Col1) values (3)
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK;END
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 BEGIN INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error) VALUES (1); BEGIN TRANSACTION;END
GO

-- this at the end 
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update succeeded.'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'The transacted portion of the database update failed.'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
```

Comment: Why not try/catch instead of all this extra stuff going on here? This is how we had to do this kind of thing in sql 2000 but for the last decade we can use try/catch blocks instead.

Comment: Thank you Erlis. I was afraid that something like what you suggest is needed. Your solution does seem to solve the problem, but, as you suspected, not as easy as I hoped for.

Comment: Sean, I tried to use a try/catch block, but it seems like you can't use batches/GOs within them.

Comment: It really depend on what you want, the solution presented by Sean will work most of the time, but just be aware that try/catch won't capture all the errors. Take a looke here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6018807/212944 but try/catch might be all that you need.

Comment: I forgot to say that this is the method used by SSDT when it generates the deployment script. Probably it will detect more failures and that's why they use it instead of try/catch. But I agree that try/catch is easier to apply to a script.

Comment: @Andvik maybe that's the reason why the SSDT team uses this approach, because the GO. Now you can decide, to GO or not to GO :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this using TRY/CATCH blocks. You can read more about that here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

```
begin transaction

begin try
    insert into Table1 (Col1) values (1);
    insert into Table1 (Col1) values (2/0);
    insert into Table1 (Col1) values (3);
    commit transaction;
end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        , ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    rollback transaction;
end catch;
```