# Using transaction rolled back for testing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, testing

I just discovered the idea of testing a stored proc by calling it from within a `BEGIN TRAN t1`  `ROLLBACK TRAN t1` pair.
I am a bit afraid of this. **Is that a common practice ? Is it reliable ?**
My goal here is to quicly test a stored proc that reads and updates 2 databases (same server). The SP does not do any truncate but uses a table variable combined with an `INSERT.. OUTPUT` statement.
The volume will be low (less than 1000 lines affected). 
Thanks

Comment: I do this frequently, and have never had a problem with it.

Comment: @JohnD: Thanks. I just "discouvered" this, looks like a nice timesaver

Comment: As far as it goes, yes. It just shows that the stored procedures don't throw errors. It doesn't show that they do the right thing. If they did nothing at all they'd pass these tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that can go wrong:

- The proc could do its own transaction management
- It could execute non-transactable statements like `CREATE DATABASE`
- It could have an error, causing the transaction to automatically rollback. If the proc then continues to run in some way, it might write stuff outside of a transaction
- [XACT_ABORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290997/what-is-the-effect-of-having-xact-abort-on-off-in-parent-child-stored-procedures) might be used inconsistently, causing the previously mentioned effect

In general, this is a good technique, though.

Truncate is transacted, btw.

Comment: upvoted and +1 for the truncate because there's a myth truncate table cannot be rolled back

Comment: @jean that's why I said it. I don't know where that myth is coming from. DROP TABLE is also transacted. All TRUNCATE does is set the b-tree root to an empty page and deallocate the rest on commit. The b-tree root can be rolled back easily.