# Log custom error message using try and catch block in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert a duplicate value in to a primary key column which raises a primary key violation error.I want to  log this error inside the catch block .

Code Block :-

```
   SET XACT_ABORT OFF
   BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRAN
   INSERT INTO #Calender values (9,'Oct')
   INSERT INTO #Calender values (2,'Unknown')
   COMMIT TRAN
   END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH 
  Insert into #LogError values (1,'Error while inserting a duplicate value')
  if @@TRANCOUNT >0
  rollback tran
  raiserror('Error while inserting a duplicate value ',16,20)
  END CATCH
```

when i execute the above code it prints out the   custom error message which is displayed in the catch block but doesn't insert the value in to the #LogError table

```
Error while inserting a duplicate value
```

But when i use SET XACT_ABORT ON i get a different error message but still it doesn't inserts the error message into the table

```
 The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations
 that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

My question is

1.How to log error into the table

2.Why do i get different error message when i set xact_ABORT on .Is it a good practice to set XACT_ABORT on before every transaction

Comment: Regarding good practice see [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1150350/73226) and discussion in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does insert the record into `#LogError` but then you rollback the transaction which removes it.

You need to do the insert after the rollback or insert into a table variable instead (that are not affected by the rollback).

When an error is encountered in the try block this can leave your transaction in a [doomed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/05/11/errors-raised-with-severity-level-16-may-cause-transactions-into-doomed-state.aspx) state. You should test the value of `XACT_STATE()` ([see example c in the `TRY ... CATCH` topic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) in the catch block to check for this before doing anything that writes to the log or trying to commit.

When `XACT_ABORT` is on any error of severity > 10 in a try block will have this effect.

Comment: So basically i should write to the log file when   XACT_STATE()=0 and when it is 1 or -1 i should rollback the trasnaction .Is it rit ?

Comment: @praveen - When it is 1 you can perform actions that write to the log if you want to.

Comment: Martin :I think XACT_STATE() will never be 1 if i get an error in try block because the transaction will be in uncommitable state .So i think it should be placed inside the code block when xact_state()=-1 The code which i have written is  if XACT_STATE()=-1
 BEGIN
 rollback tran
Insert into #LogError values (1,'Error while inserting a duplicate value')
END

Comment: @praveen - It can be 1 in a try block if the code isn't been run with `XACT_ABORT ON` otherwise yes I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

As SqlServer doesn't support `Autonomous transaction` (nested and independent transaction), it's not possible *(in fact, you can, under some condition, use CLR SP with custom connectstring - doing it's own, non local, connection)* to use a database table to log SP execution activity/error messages.

To fix, this missing functionnality, I've developed a toolbox (100% T-SQL) based on the use of **XML** parameter passed as reference (OUTPUT parameter) which is filled during SP execution and can be save into a dedicated database table at the end.

*Disclamer: I'm a Iorga employee (cofounder) and I've developped the following LGPL v3 toolbox. My objective is not Iorga/self promotion but sharing knowledge and simplify T-SQL developper life.*

See, teach, enhance as you wish [SPLogger](https://github.com/iorga-group/splogger)

Today (October 19th of 2015) I've just released the 1.3 including a **Unit Test System** based on SPLogger.