# which is better approach for roll back transaction in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions, rollback

I came to know we can go for roll back transaction using "**set xact_abort on**"
i want to know which is the better way for roll back transaction: use "set xact_abort on" or simple the following code

```
begin try
begin tran
-- statements 
commit tran
end try
begin catch
rollback tran
end catch
```

Please help me to choose which is better approach while inserting number of records one time.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150032/

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned is what I normally follow since it allows handling error conditions in a graceful manner. You can log extra information like source/proc params used etc in catch block when used in a proc.