# SQL automatically throw if a statement fails?

Tags: sql

Is there any way to have a stored procedure automatically `throw` if any statement fails due to an error?

I'm inside a stored proc with a `merge` statement which can fail due to a primary key violation, however execution still continues.

Do I have to resort to `if @@error != 0 throw ...` everywhere?

EDIT: I'm using MS SQL Server 2012

EDIT:  This seems to work, but is there a less verbose solution?  It seems as if the introduction of `try/catch` makes flow jump to the `catch` block when an error is encountered.  From there I just rethrow the exception.

```
begin try    
    ....do lots of sql code
end try
begin catch
    throw;
end catch
```

Comment: What *kind* of SQL?  Do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: One of the great benefits offered by the `MERGE` statement is that you can decide on performing a different action when certain criteria occur (e.g. PK violation). Why do you wish to use a different method?

Comment: `merge` is just an example.  it could be any statement that fails for any reason (eg a bug).

Answer (score 3):

Use `SET xact_abort ON` at the beginning of the statement.  It will cause an automatic rollback if any particular statement fails.

See [What is the benefit of using "SET XACT_ABORT ON" in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150032/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-set-xact-abort-on-in-a-stored-procedure).

Edit: the above is for SQL-Server.

Comment: I'm not inside a transaction so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Add BEGIN TRANSACTION at the start of the SP and COMMIT TRANSACTION at the end.
Similar to logixologist's example.

Comment: That has semantic and performance implications that I don't want.  I'm not interested in rolling back the code execution that has successfully completed.  I'm looking for semantics similar to C# exceptions.

Comment: @CoderBrien So, if one row fails on a MERGE, you don't want it to rollback the whole thing - you want it only to throw on the rows that have an error?

Comment: @Question3CPO: I'm not looking to rollback any changes that have occurred prior to the error, I'm just trying to halt execution.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping it in a transaction so that if anything fails it will roll back any changes and you can have it return an error message.

Something like

```
BEGIN Transaction
--Do some code

if @@error > 0 
BEGIN
--Do your throw here and then
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
ELSE

BEGIN
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: I don't understand your code.  Is a check for `@@error` required inside a transaction?  If so, then what exactly is the purpose of wrapping the code with a transaction?

Comment: I have always learned it that way. I could be mistaken. The purpose of the transaction is you could have done 100 things AFTER begin transaction. If anything fails in that it will catch it and rollback everything

Comment: One option... why not put in your throws in the if @error = and commit the transaction anyway... untested advice btw but it might work

Comment: I don't want transaction semantics.  I want to retain changes and halt execution at the point of the error.