# SET_XACT_ABORT ON in a transaction with rollback present in catch block

Tags: transactions, xact-abort

Just going through some tutorials at the moment and I see a lot of code in stored procedures as follows.

SET_XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRY
....
   COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH

Just wondering why would the SET_XACT_ABORT ON here would be necessary as wouldn't any throw or raise error be caught in the Catch block anyway and the transaction will be rolled back?

Thanks

Comment: a quick search for SET_XACT_ABORT ON would answer your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150032/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-set-xact-abort-on-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: To be honest it still does not really answer why it would be necessary seeing there is a catch block there with a rollback statement

Comment: Sorry it explains it...my bad

Comment: Could you please answer your question here? 'Cause I still cannot find an answer in the question mentioned above by Mitch Wheat in comments to your question.