# Terminating a job in SQL Server during runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-job

Is there a way to make a scheduled job terminate (stop, quit, stop executing, report failure) within a stored procedure in that job?

For example, I have some check queries within a `TRY` block that do `RAISERROR (59834,16,1)` to go to the `CATCH` block to send an email saying that the check queries found a bad situation and the job must stop. The number 59834 was arbitrary but specific.
However, every time I test the job, even though I raised an error, the job continues to execute; it never reports a failure.

I have tried using the same `RAISERROR` in the `CATCH` block as I did in the `TRY` block, but that did not work either.

I want the job to stop in this once instance, it will run every day.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the XACT_ABORT setting is not on.  Without XACT_ABORT on, the execution will continue regardless of any errors encountered.  More information about XACT_ABORT:

[Microsoft BOL entry for XACT_ABORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)

[What is the benefit of using SET XACT_ABORT ON in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150032/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-set-xact-abort-on-in-a-stored-procedure)

So you might consider a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the start of the job.