# TSQL: TRY CATCH error handling with logging errors into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

Using SQL Server 2014:

I am going through the following article that includes useful patterns for TSQL error handling:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175976.aspx

I like to log errors so later on I can query, monitor, track and inspect the errors took place in my application's store procedures.

I was thinking to create a table and insert the error details as a row into the table in the CATCH block; however I am concern this might not be a good pattern OR there might be a built-in SQL server feature that can log the errors generated by the ;THROW statement.

What would be the best way to log the errors?

**Update 1**

I should mention that I always set XACT_ABORT on top of my SPs:

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

Is it safe to assume that there is no way to log errors when XACT_ABORT is ON?

**Update 2**

The SET XACT_ABORT ON is according to this post:

http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpXACT_ABORT

Can xp_logevent be a better alternative than adding an error record to a log table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be very careful with logging from CATCH locks. First and foremost, you **must** check the [`XACT_STATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) and honor it. If xact_state is -1 (
'uncommittable transaction') you cannot do any transactional operation, so the INSERT fail. You must first rollback, then insert. But you cannot simply rollback, because you may be in xact_state 0 (no transaction) in which case rollback would fail. And if xact_state is 1, you are still in the original transaction, and your INSERT may still be rolled back *later* and you'll loose all track of this error ever occurring.

Another approach to consider is to generate a user defined profiler event using [`sp_trace_generateevent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177548.aspx) and have a system trace monitoring your user event ID. This works in any xact_state state and has the advantage of keeping the record even if the encompassing transaction will roll back later.

> I should mention that I always set XACT_ABORT

Stop doing this. Read [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for a good SP pattern vis-a-vis error handling and transactions.

Comment: The XACT_ABORT idea came from this post: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpXACT_ABORT . The problem with sp_trace_generateevent  is that it always needs a profiling listener. It does not record the error. Can we use xp_logevent instead?

Comment: I have a lot of respect for Erland, but on the issue of XACT_ABORT I disagree with him.

Comment: as for the trace listener, there is a way: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2010/10/17/logging-messages-during-a-transaction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is better.
If you want to store then try this.

```
declare @Error_msg_desc    varchar(500)
,@Error_err_code   int            
,@Error_sev_num int        
,@Error_proc_nm varchar(100)     
,@Error_line_num    int     
begin try
    select 1/0
end try
begin catch
    select   @Error_err_code = ERROR_NUMBER()         
            ,@Error_msg_desc = ERROR_MESSAGE()       
            ,@Error_sev_num  = ERROR_SEVERITY()        
            ,@Error_proc_nm  = ERROR_PROCEDURE()        
            ,@Error_line_num = ERROR_LINE() 
    --create SqlLog Table       
    --Insert into Log Table 
    Insert into Sqllog values(@Error_err_code,@Error_msg_desc,@Error_sev_num,@Error_proc_nm,@Error_line_num)            
end catch
```

Comment: It will rollback whole transaction and abort that batch but not able log error.

Comment: So, is it safe to assume that no error logging possible with SET XACT_ABORT ON?

Comment: I am not having to much knowledge **XACT_ABORT** of  but see this article hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1150069/5897242