# Do I need to set XACT_ABORT to ON in every trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, triggers

This was an old SQL Server 2008 Express database (five of them actually) that I just migrated to SQL Server 2019 Express. Everything seemed to be working fine until my crew got in and we were getting an error everywhere. Turns out we had `RAISEERROR` in the triggers, and even though my compatibility appears to be set to 2008 (100), we were still getting the error. So I upgraded to `THROW`. Now everything appears to work fine, but as I'm not a DBA, I'm worried that my upgrade my corrupt some data or leave orphans. Here's an example of one of the triggers:

```
USE [toddAPB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[T_tSaleLineItem_ITrig]    Script Date: 5/18/2021 1:32:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_tSaleLineItem_ITrig] ON [dbo].[tSaleLineItem] FOR INSERT AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
/* * PREVENT INSERTS IF NO MATCHING KEY IN 'tProduct' */
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) !=
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tProduct, inserted WHERE (tProduct.RecNumP = inserted.RecNumP))
    BEGIN
        ;THROW 44447, 'The record can''t be added or changed. Referential integrity rules require a related record in table ''tProduct''.',1;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

/* * PREVENT INSERTS IF NO MATCHING KEY IN 'tSale' */
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) !=
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tSale, inserted WHERE (tSale.RecNumS = inserted.RecNumS))
    BEGIN
        ;THROW 44447, 'The record can''t be added or changed. Referential integrity rules require a related record in table ''tSale''.',1;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

Do I need to put `SET XACT_ABORT ON` on every trigger (hundreds of them)? Should I? Do I still need `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` after every `THROW`?

Before I adjusted to `THROW`, I was getting the "syntax error near 44447" error. the line previously looked more like this:

```
RAISERROR 44447 'The record can''t be added or changed. Referential integrity rules require a related record in table ''tProduct''.'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is the default for a trigger. How is this related to changing from `raiserror` to `throw`? Also `throw` rolls back by default. Also if you correctly terminate your statements with a `;` you don't need to add one in front of your `throw` (but SSMS will still show it as red because of a bug). And what was the actual error you were getting? `raiserror` is still supported?

Comment: @DaleK From what I understand, it changes whether `THROW` will rollback the transaction or not. So I my assumption is that if it is off, it won't rollback the transaction and it will not execute the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` code either.

Comment: As I said `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is implicitly on for a trigger unless you turn it off.

Comment: @DaleK The error I was getting was Incorrect SQL Syntax near 44447. Adjusting to `THROW` fixed it.

Comment: As we can't see your old code we can't assist with that. Not that its a bad thing to move to throw, but as you have worked out it does change the behaviour, so you might have been better off fixing the original error.

Comment: @DaleK according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150032/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-set-xact-abort-on-in-a-stored-procedure?rq=1, `XACT_ABORT` is not on by default.... which is it?!

Comment: @DauntlessRob I would believe the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) over a SO question.

Comment: With regard to the link above, it doesn't mention triggers. XACT_ABORT is off by default in other contexts, but not in a trigger. Consequently, I turn it on in every SP.

Comment: You can configure xact_abort to be on at the server level, which would make more sense if you are setting it for every procedure?

Comment: I suggest implementing the appropriate foreign key constraints and dumping this trigger completely.

Comment: @Stu Thanks! I didn't know that. Just turned it on... waiting for the screams...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well really you should be solving this issue with a Foreign Key Constraint (thanks Charlieface), however if thats not practical read on...

[`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the default for a trigger.

> OFF is the default setting in a T-SQL statement, while ON is the default setting in a trigger.

You should also be using *proper* joins rather than implicit joins. I have laid it out how I would write a trigger, with correctly terminated statements.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_tSaleLineItem_ITrig]
ON [dbo].[tSaleLineItem]
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /* PREVENT INSERTS IF NO MATCHING KEY IN 'tProduct' */
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) != (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tProduct P INNER JOIN inserted I ON P.RecNumP = I.RecNumP)
    BEGIN
        THROW 44447, 'The record can''t be added or changed. Referential integrity rules require a related record in table ''tProduct''.', 1;
    END;

    /* PREVENT INSERTS IF NO MATCHING KEY IN 'tSale' */
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) != (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tSale S INNER JOIN inserted I ON S.RecNumS = I.RecNumS)
    BEGIN
        THROW 44447, 'The record can''t be added or changed. Referential integrity rules require a related record in table ''tSale''.', 1;
    END;
END;
```

You could of course continue to use [`RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but it appears the syntax has changed since you originally wrote it - so you would have to correct that. Since you are having to modify them all anyway, moving to [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) seems appropriate.

I find your integrity check interesting, I would have written it as follows due to how I approach the logic, but I don't think its any better.

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Inserted I
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tProduct P WHERE P.RecNumP = I.RecNumP)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great help. (It was several predecessors before me that set all this up, and I'm not trained in DBA.)

Comment: Obviously you would use an FK not a trigger to do an integrity check anyway