# Insert data into 2 related tables at once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into two tables at once using the primary key from the first table to insert into the second but I am not sure how to go about it.

My table structure is as follows:

**Person**

```
PersonId
FirstName
Surname
```

**Employee**

```
EmployeeId
HoursWorked
```

`PersonId` in the `Person` table is an auto incremented column. `EmployeeId` in the second table is a primary and foreign key that should be the same as `PersonId`.

I been trying with this query string which I found on Google but with not much luck:

```
string queryString = "BEGIN TRANSACTION DECLARE @DataID int; "
 +"INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, Surname) VALUES(@firstName, @surname);" 
 + "SELECT @DataID = scope_identity();" 
 + "INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(@DataId, @hoursWorked);" 
 + "COMMIT";
```

Comment: Are you looking for a T-SQL stored procedure to do this? Or some programming language code to handle this? If so: **what** programming language?

Comment: I am doing this inside a C# function in a Windows Forms App.

Comment: See either `scope_identity` or `output` clause.

Comment: What code do you have so far? How many rows are you inserting

Comment: I am inserting just one row at a time.

Comment: I been trying with this query string which I found on Google but with not much luck:


`string queryString = "BEGIN TRANSACTION DECLARE @DataID int; " 
+"INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, Surname) VALUES(@firstName, @surname);" 
+ "SELECT @DataID = scope_identity();" 
+ "INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(@DataId, @hoursWorked);" 
+ "COMMIT";`

Comment: And what exactly is going wrong with that?

Comment: Are you familar with the concept of the transactions (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: I am getting an error about "column name or number of supplied values does not matching table definition"

Comment: It's been a while since I read up on transactions but my memory is that if one part of the transaction fails they all fail so that you don't get partial data in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From C#, you can try something like this:

```
// define the INSERT query - insert a firstname,surname into "Person",
// and insert a row into the Emplyoee table with the new ID
// created by the first insert
string insertStmt = @"BEGIN TRANSACTION
                      INSERT INTO dbo.Person(FirstName, Surname) VALUES(@FirstName, @Surname);
                      DECLARE @NewPersonId INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                      INSERT INTO dbo.Employee(EmployeeId, HoursWorked) VALUES(@NewPersonId, @HoursWorked);
                      COMMIT TRANSACTION;"

// define connection and command for inserting data                       
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn))
{
    // Define parameters - adapt datatype and max length as required
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@HoursWorked", SqlDbType.Int);
    
    // set parameter values
    cmdInsert.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = "John";
    cmdInsert.Parameters["@Surname"].Value = "Doe";
    cmdInsert.Parameters["@HoursWorked"].Value = 35;
    
    // Open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    
    int rowsInserted = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    conn.Close();
}
```

**Update**: as mentioned by @charlieface, you can write this code more concisely **IF** you're only ever inserting a single row - like this:

```
// define connection and command for inserting data                       
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn))
{
    // Define and set parameters
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "John";
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "Doe";
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@HoursWorked", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 35;
    
    // Open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    int rowsInserted = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Nice and neat. `cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "....";` more concise. Also probably best to `SET XACT_ABORT ON`

Comment: @Charlieface: I've come to avoid that "more concise" style - if you have the need to insert 10 rows, one after another - it's better to have explicit steps to *define* the parameters (once, before a loop), and a second step to actually set the parameter values (inside a loop, to handle the multiple inserts). But for a single insert - I agree, that style would be preferable

Comment: I hear you, although for multi-row inserts I tend to use either a Table Valued Parameter or `SqlBulkCopy` anyway

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the columns you are inserting into.

> You should also use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` if you have an explicit transaction.
>
> Note also the use of a multi-line string.

```cs
string queryString = @"
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Person (FirstName, Surname)
VALUES(@firstName, @surname);
DECLARE @DataID int = scope_identity();

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeId, HoursWorked)
VALUES(@DataId, @hoursWorked);

COMMIT;
";
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this explicit transaction thing but I will add it in.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1150069/14868997