SQL Server Index strategy for comparing date columns in a table
I have a SQL Server table with a recurring query that I need to improve the performance of it. I need to retrieve rows matching the WHERE clause shown here. All 3 columns are defined as datetime2 columns.
WHERE GREATEST(dateColumn1, dateColumn2) > dateColumn3

What is the best way to index the table to improve performance?
Should I create a computed column and index that?

Indexes won't help. You're calling a function on every row, with the result not known until the function returns.

@KenWhite GREATEST is not an opaque function though (unless it is?) - I was operating on the understanding that the T-SQL engine knows GREATEST( x, y, z ) is equivalent to CASE WHEN x > y AND x > z THEN x WHEN y > x AND y > z THEN y WHEN z > x AND z > y THEN z ELSE NULL END (...right?) - which means it can use range-queries.

BTW, I see no reason to use GREATEST here anyway: because GREATEST(dateColumn1, dateColumn2) > dateColumn3 is equivalent to dateCol1 > dateCol3 OR dateCol2 > dateCol3 which should be SARGable too.

Are the dateColumn1 and/or dateColumn2 columns NULL or NOT NULL?

@Dai: I hadn't considered it that way. Thanks for the education. :-) I wouldn't have used GREATEST myself - I find the equivalent you put in your second comment much easier to read and understand when coming back to maintain the code months after writing it.

Not much to go on but my instincts tell me numbered recurring columns needing queries like this generally suggests a normalization issue. The dates probably need to be in a single column of a related table with another column to designate which of the recurring date columns they belong to.

@Galaxiom Even if that is the case (and I hope it isn't, because that's a multiplicity design change, so it would be incredibly awkard to deal-with in both SQL and application-code - there's also a potentially huge problem in that moving a fixed, well-defined set of columns into their own table as rows means you no-longer have the abiltiy to set CONSTRAINT rules on those columns now, such as the inability to assert that such a collection is always non-empty. (And this is why SQL needs real reform, not more bolted-on XML/JSON support; and I'm ranting again, ughhhhhh).

@Dai - dateColumn1 > dateColumn3 OR dateColumn2 > dateColumn3 still isn't sargable. Column to column comparisons are not sargable. You wouldn't know the value to seek until you are already on the row to know what dateColumn3 is

@MartinSmith "Column to column comparisons are not sargable." - you're probably right, but I can't find any good sources for this - and I can think-up some scenarios where multiple indexes could be used by a sufficiently advanced query engine (granted, that's when I mentally squint when thinking...).


What is the best way to index the table to improve performance?

Make your WHERE predicate clause expression into a computed-column and then index that column.

Last time I checked, SQL Server (incl. Azure SQL) does not support using arbitrary expressions in a CREATE INDEX statement, so any expressions you want to index must be defined as computed (but not necessarily PERSISTED) columns.
...I was doing this myself a few months ago, but I ran into a -inducing bug: you actually need to use PERSISTED if you use LEAST or GREATEST in a computed-column expression in SQL Server 2022 or Azure SQL.

Now, because you'll need to define a computed-column that'll be indexed as-is then consider that you could either...

Define the computed-column simply as the result of GREATEST( col1, col2, etc ) - which means you'll still need the > comparison in your SELECT query, and potentially experience poor query-plan selection if even the slightest change happens to your DB.

...or: define another computed-column using the result of the > expression, and INDEX over that; you'll need to update your SELECT queries to directly reference the new computed-columns, but this significantly reduces the odds of SQL Server generating a bad query-plan (but YMMV, ofc).


(I assume your dateCol1 and dateCol2 columns are both datetime2(7) NOT NULL. (If they actually are NULL-able then this answer probably won't work for you because the computed-column and index here won't handle dateCol1 IS NOT NULL or dateCol1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM dateCol2-style predicates)
Anyway, like so:
-- Before doing anything, ensure we're in a deterministic and standards-compliant environment, which is important for PERSISTED columns:

SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

SET XACT_ABORT ON; /* See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150032/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-set-xact-abort-on-in-a-stored-procedure */

BEGIN TRANSACTION ddlTxn;

RAISERROR( 'Now running ALTER TABLE...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
    ADD
        Greatest_1_or_2        AS GREATEST( dateCol1, dateCol2 ) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
        DateCol_1_or_2_is_gt_3 AS ( CASE WHEN GREATEST( dateCol1, dateCol2 ) > dateCol3 THEN CONVERT(bit,1) ELSE CONVERT(bit,0) END ) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
        DateCol_1_or_2_diff_3  AS ( DATEDIFF( microsecond, GREATEST( dateCol1, dateCol2 ) - dateCol3 ) PERSISTED NOT NULL;

GO /* This `GO` is to stop SSMS complaining that the computed cols ( defined above, but used below) won't exist at parse-time. */

RAISERROR( 'Now running CREATE INDEX...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

CREATE INDEX IX_Greatest12 ON dbo.MyTable ( Greatest_1_or_2 ) INCLUDE ( dateCol3 );

CREATE INDEX IX_Greatest12IsGT3 ON dbo.MyTable ( DateCol_1_or_2_is_gt_3 );

CREATE INDEX IX_DateCol12Diff3 ON dbo.MyTable ( DateCol_1_or_2_diff_3 );

RAISERROR( 'COMMITing TRANSACTION...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

COMMIT TRANSACTION ddlTxn;

RAISERROR( 'Ding!', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

Notice that I defined DateCol_1_or_2_is_gt_3 and DateCol_1_or_2_diff_3 - and associated IX_ indexes - so you'll likely want to choose one bunch or the other (or both?) based on your actual queries.
So your queries might now look like this:
SELECT /* ... */ FROM dbo.MyTable AS t WHERE t.Greatest_1_or_2 > t.dateCol3

or:
SELECT /* ... */ FROM dbo.MyTable AS t WHERE t.DateCol_1_or_2_is_gt_3 = 1;

or:
SELECT /* ... */ FROM dbo.MyTable AS t WHERE t.DateCol_1_or_2_diff_3 < 0;


You'll need to test-out and benchmark these 3 different variations for yourself because whichever is faster or preferable overall depends entirely on how the rest of your DB works, and from my vantage-point here, on the Internet, I can't see anything :)

I see a couple of options:
You can create an index on TableName(dateColumn1, dateColumn2, dateColumn3). SQL Server can perform an index scan and evaluate the condition for each row without performing a more costly table scan. This assumes the "width" of your table (the composite of all of the columns) is much greater than the three date columns. NOTE: While testing, I was unable to coax SQL Server into actually using this index over a table scan, unless I added an explicit index hint. This might just be insufficient test data, or it there might be some other limiting condition.
I believe the difference between GREATEST(dateColumn1, dateColumn2) > dateColumn3 vs dateColumn1 > dateColumn3 OR dateColumn2 > dateColumn3 is negligible compared to the cost of the underlying index data retrieval, but given a choice the latter might have a slight performance advantage.
Another option is to add a computed column to your table and index the result, such as:
ALTER TABLE Data
    ADD isInteresting AS
        CASE WHEN dateColumn1 > dateColumn3 OR dateColumn2 > dateColumn3
        THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
        PERSISTED

CREATE INDEX IX_Data_isInteresting ON Data(isInteresting)

You would then change your query condition to just WHERE isInteresting = 1.
Side Note: An index may be defined on a computed column only if either (1) the computed column expression is considered "precise" by SQL Server or (2) the computed column is defined as PERSISTED. Since the GREATEST() function is not considered a "precise" function by SQL Server (possibly due to its support for floating point values), its use would require a persisted computed column. The dateColumn1 > dateColumn3 OR dateColumn2 > dateColumn3 alternative does not need to be persisted.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo showing execution plans.

"is negligible compared to the cost of the underlying index data retrieval." - Yes, but consider the cost of index updates.
