# What are steps to Profile a SQL Stored Procedure for execution counts and running time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, testing, stored-procedures

#### Somewhat Related

[What are the best practices in writing a sql stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303417/what-are-the-best-practices-in-writing-a-sql-stored-procedure)

#### Question

I have written a sql-xml stored procedure in Microsoft SQL server express 2005, now how does one find how many executions it can do in a second, time it takes for the same and how to do load testing on the same. Are there any open source tool for the same? Is there any pattern i can follow for improving the execution count? What performance bottlenecks do stored procedure generally face?

Comment: [How Can I Log and Find the Most Expensive Queries?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Surfer513 Database Administrators profile queries? i thought the developer was in charge of it.[I do]

Comment: @MitchWheat The related post does not relate to my question, but does fall under profiling and designing queries

Comment: @Deeptechtons: actually it does relate to your question.

Comment: @MitchWheat could you rewrite that post for sql server 2005 express as the answer for me to accept, because i was not possible to find few items from that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using duration, I would examine the reads performed by setting `SET STATISTICS IO ON`, as this is not sensitive to server environmental load.

Include the 'Actual Execution Plan'. Examine the plan and look for:

- Large Table or Index scans
- Bookmark lookups that can be eliminated by creating covering indexes (that are not too wide...)
- Large Discrepancies in "Actual Rows. versus 'Estimated Rows' (usually an indication that statistics are out of date).

Also see: [How Can I Log and Find the Most Expensive Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257906/how-can-i-log-and-find-the-most-expensive-queries)

Comment: when you mean `Examine plan for Large Table or Index scans` could you put it in more detail so when i see the execution plan i know where to look at[i mean like does SSSms show these in red colors, big blocks etc]

Comment: will try to update in a few hours...

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is utilize `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` to see the duration of the stored procedure.  That'll give you a good idea of how many iterations will be able to take place in a second.  Then to optimize/tune that stored procedure just view the *actual execution plan* and see what the most expensive portions of the stored procedure are.

And it'll heed you to use the stored procedure as a workload in the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.  You may get a few hints as to missing indexes, possible improvements, etc.