# MySQL: Run a stored procedure getting parameter from a query inside another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to MySQL.

I am developing a system where many users are assigned to specific tasks. When they are inactive for a certain period of time (lets say more than 10 minutes) I would like the system automatically clear their assignments so that others can work on them.

To achieve that I have created a table called **[tblactivitytracker](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8b93/2)** for activity tracking. Assignments are in a table called **[tblinquiries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71739cb/1)**. I have created a stored procedure to get the inactive users.

Here is an sqlfiddle example: [Get Inactive Users](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6e573/4)

In the above example I get 3 inactive users: auditor1, auditor2 and auditor3.

I have created a stored procedure to clear assignment of a single user which does the job perfectly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spClearAssignedInquiry`(IN `pAssignedTo` VARCHAR(50))
UPDATE
        tblinquiries
SET
        AuditStatus='Check', AssignedTo=NULL, Result=NULL,
        ResultCategories=NULL, AuditBy=NULL,
        Remarks=NULL, StartTime=NULL, EndTime=NULL
WHERE
        AssignedTo=pAssignedTo AND
        AuditStatus='Assigned' AND EndTime IS NULL
```

If I pass auditor1 as a parameter in the above procedure it will clear the user's assignment.

To pass all inactive users and clear the assignments in a single go I tried the below procedure following [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326775/call-a-stored-procedure-for-each-row-returned-by-a-query-in-mysql):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spInactiveUsers`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE AssignedTo VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
    q1.AssignedTo  AS AssignedTo
FROM 
    (SELECT
        InquiryId, AssignedTo
    FROM
        tblinquiries
    WHERE
        AuditStatus='Assigned' AND StartTime IS NOT NULL AND EndTime IS NULL
    ORDER BY
        AssignedTo ASC
    ) q1
RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT
        UserId, MAX(LastActivity) AS LastActivity, ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(LastActivity),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))/60,0) AS InactiveMinutes
    FROM 
        tblactivitytracker
    GROUP BY
        UserId
    ORDER BY
        LastActivity ASC
    ) q2
ON
    q2.UserId=q1.AssignedTo
WHERE
    q2.InactiveMinutes>10;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  testLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO AssignedTo;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE testLoop;
    END IF;
    CALL spClearAssignedInquiry(AssignedTo);
  END LOOP testLoop;

  CLOSE cur;
END
```

But it does not clear any of the assignments.

I am banging my head to the wall for the last couple of days. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Separately the queries run without any problem. Here is the data in fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6e573/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a variable name that is also the name of a column. The value of the variable  will take precedence over the column value, see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a SELECT ... INTO statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable.

So in

```
...
FROM 
 (SELECT
     InquiryId, AssignedTo
...
```

you are selecting the variable `AssignedTo` (which is `null`), not the column from your table.

Just rename it (in `declare` and the loop), or, less advised, explicitly state the tablename to set the scope, e.g. `SELECT  InquiryId, tblinquiries.AssignedTo .... order by tblinquiries.AssignedTo`.

There is another (minor) problem is your use of [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) in `TIMEDIFF(MAX(LastActivity), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())`. It requires the later time in the first argument if you want to get a positive number (as in `q2.InactiveMinutes>10`).

Comment: Thank you very much! I renamed the variable and that did the trick.