# Check if current date is between 2 dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a contract table in my database and those contracts have a start date and an end date. How can I change their active state if the current date is after the end date?

I already figured out that I'll do it with a stored procedure that gets executed every day or something like that. My Problem is, I don't know, how I can check each row in the table. It seems like something extremely basic yet I can't think of any solution.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14327995/10871765) Response and it looks very promising but I'm afraid I don't understand the way it's supposed to work.

I'd highly appreciate any and all pointers.

EDIT: I found the solution and my way of approaching the problem was way off.

Comment: To update all relevant rows, you write an UPDATE query and in the WHERE clause you specifiy the criteria of the rows you actually want to apply your update to

Comment: Are `startdate` and `enddate` defined as DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatypes?

Comment: So `UPDATE table SET status=0 WHERE CURDATE() > enddate`

Comment: @RiggsFolly They're DATETIME

Comment: Then see above comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, that worked, my approach would have been so much more complicated.

Comment: You can use `date()` function to type cast column value like that `WHERE CURDATE() > date(enddate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) I found the solution:

```
UPDATE contract_conclusion SET is_active=0 WHERE CURDATE() > date_end_contract_conclusion;
```

Comment: While this may solve your problem, it certainly doesn't satisfy the question posed in the title.

Comment: @Strawberry Why not? It just means that I approached the problem completely wrong, more from a PHP-Coder point of view without considering the database-oriented approach. So now I managed to solve it the way a problem like this is supposed to be solved, and not in the way I originally intended to.