# SQL Selecting a list of Ids and run them through SP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I just started SQL with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to select a list of Ids and run each of them through a stored procedure but am not sure how to do it.

```
SELECT Id 
FROM UserId 
WHERE ProgramId = @ProgramId
```

Then, I have created a procedure called `temp_sp_UpdateIds`

Normally I can just run the stored procedure with

```
EXEC temp_sp_UpdateIds @ProgramId
```

but I am not sure how to run the stored procedure with the list of Ids returned from the select statement and place it under `@ProgramId`

Do I need to store the Ids in a local table or something?

Thanks.

Comment: does the stored proc return a value?

Comment: nop, the stored proc simply inserts

Comment: Try this SO [solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/886314/125551) or you can change your SP to a function and then you can call function  in sql query itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Creating a Table Type and SP

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfIds AS TABLE(Id int PRIMARY KEY)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.temp_sp_UpdateIds
 (
  @ListOfIds dbo.ListOfIds READONLY
  )
AS
BEGIN
...body of procedure
END
GO
```

Calling a Procedure with a Table-Valued Parameter

```
DECLARE @ListOfIds dbo.ListOfIds
INSERT @ListOfIds
SELECT Id
FROM UserId
WHERE ProgramId = @ProgramId

EXEC dbo.temp_sp_UpdateIds @ListOfIds
```

See [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/feae1/2)

Comment: thx! I am trying to do this but how do I use ``@ListOfIds`` inside my sp?  When I ref to the variable it returns ``Must declare the scalar variable @ListOfIds``?  And for the table-valued paramters/table type, is it simply creating a temporary table which only in the scope of the script?  thx in advance.

Comment: I suggested using Table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to procedure, without creating a temporary table.Inside procedure you can only read data from a Table-valued parameter (e.g. perform whether operations a restrict or filtering data, etc.) In some cases better performance than temporary tables or other ways to pass a list of parameters. In answer was added a simple demo.

Answer (score 2):

You're unfortunately looking a cursor. Concept is you will provide your query in the first block, declare the variable(s) you'll need to operate your proc and then iterate through them.

```
DECLARE CSR CURSOR
READ_ONLY
FOR SELECT ProgramId FROM UserId 

DECLARE @programid int
OPEN CSR

FETCH NEXT FROM CSR INTO @programid
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE temp_sp_UpdateIds @programId
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM CSR INTO @programId
END

CLOSE CSR

DEALLOCATE CSR
GO
```

The other option that comes to mind is to generate the EXEC calls in SQL, concatenate all of that together with a semicolon and then exec that.

Comment: Do you mean @programId in the first fetch?

Comment: @JohnDewey I wasn't quite sure how the OP used it. They are executing a SELECT based on the value of programid in the query but then using that same programid in the EXEC call. I figured they better understood their logic and just needed the basic parts of how to call a proc for each row in a resultset. I'm open to improving the clarity of the answer if you have suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the proc to a function (that returns a value - even just `null`) you can simply do this:

```
SELECT temp_sp_UpdateIds(id) FROM UserId WHERE ProgramId=@ProgramId
```

Answer (score -1):

In normal case you may do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM UserId WHERE ProgramId in (SELECT ProgramId FROM t WHERE ...)
```

If procedure fill @ParamId by somthing like select result with one column - it must work

Comment: huh? where is the call to the stored proc?