# How to pass more than one id to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query in a store procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETEREP (@id INT) 
AS 
    DELETE FROM TABLE 
    WHERE  ID = @id
```

Now I want to execute this store procedure from another stored procedure like this:

```
exec(Deleterep) from here i want to pass multiple ids like 

where  id in (selec id from table2)
```

I want to pass multiple ids to the SP. 
I don't want to call store procedure multiple time, using cursor or loop, I want to avoid it.

Can someone give me an idea of how to proceed?

Comment: What database are you using? SQLServer, MYSQL, Oracle? Also what version? Recent versions of SQLServer can use XML parameters

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I execute a stored procedure once for each row returned by query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886293/how-do-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-once-for-each-row-returned-by-query)

Comment: @rs i have gone through that link and that is using cursor, which will call the store procedure again and again i want to avoid it, please read the question again

Comment: which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: You cannot do what you want without a cursor or at least a loop and without modifying the stored procedure. point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Selecting a list of Ids and run them through SP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428243/sql-selecting-a-list-of-ids-and-run-them-through-sp)

Comment: @pavezalam, what you are trying to achieve is not possible through SP, you cannot call stored procedure as part of a sql, you need to convert that to a scalar function. Only way to do this is through cursor or write a new SP that runs actual delete statement using two tables instead of calling another SP.

Answer (score 2):

you can use XML as Devart suggested, but here's two more options.

Comma separated list (you can split it with other methods, I've used convert to xml just here):

```
create procedure usp_test1(@list nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    declare @data xml

    select @data = cast('<id>' + replace(@list, ', ', '</id><id>') + '</id>' as xml)

    select *
    from test
    where id in
      (
          select t.c.value('.', 'int') as a
          from @data.nodes('id') as t(c)
      )
end
```

or user-defined table type:

```
create type list as table (id int primary key)

create procedure usp_test2(@list list readonly)
as
begin
    select *
    from test
    where id in (select id from @list)
end
```

see [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14f36/1) with 2 examples

Comment: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks in our system we're using `usp` for prefix, it was just for example, but you're right, will change the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use this in definition of SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETEREP (@id INT,@id1 int,@id2 int) 
AS 
    DELETE FROM TABLE 
    WHERE  ID in (@id,@id1,@id2)
```

If you are taking these id's from table just declare a #temp table or table variable

Like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETEREP 

AS 

    Declare @TEMP_TABLE TABLE ( ID INT)

    INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE select id from table2

        DELETE FROM TABLE 
        WHERE  ID in (SELECT ID FROM @TEMP_TABLE)
```

OR YOU CAN Directly use your table2 in SP

Please let me know if this is of any help.

Regards,
Ashutosh Arya

Comment: i cannot modify the store procedure, its has been developed by other programer and its being used in multiple file, so i cannot modify sp, i have to just call this sp, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one -

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_DELETEREP 
(
    @XML XML
) 
AS BEGIN

    DELETE FROM dbo.[TABLE] 
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT t.c.value('.', 'BIGINT')
        FROM @XML.nodes('/data/id') t(c)
    )

END

GO

DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<data>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
</data>'

EXEC usp_DELETEREP @XML = @XML
```

Comment: i cannot modify the store procedure, its has been developed by other programer and its being used in multiple file, so i cannot modify sp, i have to just call this sp, thanks

Comment: Can you create a new stored procedure?

Comment: I can create, and I am not stuck with this problem in my work, i want to know just for knowledge , is such kind of scenario can be implemented

Comment: Yes, of course. I personally prefer `XML`, but user-defined table type also are good choice for 2008 (and higher) server version.