# How to create temp table using Create statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

How to create a temp table similarly to creating a normal table?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name 
(
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
     ....
 );
```

Comment: Just add `#` before table name

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered with a simple Google search

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A temporary table can have 3 kinds, the `#` is the most used. This is a temp table that only exists in the current session.
An equivalent of this is `@`, a declared table variable. This has a little less "functions" (like indexes etc) and is also only used for the current session.
The `##` is one that is the same as the `#`, however, the scope is wider, so you can use it within the same session, within other stored procedures.

You can create a temp table in various ways:

```
declare @table table (id int)
create table #table (id int)
create table ##table (id int)
select * into #table from xyz
```

Comment: The usage of *session* is not correct... A `@table` is - like any variable - bound to one job. It will disappear with a `GO` and a called SP or function does not know it. A `#table` will live within one session, even in a called SP or function, while a `##table` can be reached from different sessions.

Comment: Also, a table variable is not a temporary table. Read Martin Smith's [post on DBO.StackExchange about it](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386) for details.

Comment: Table variables can often lead to poor execution plans due to their lack of indexes and statistics. They are scoped to the current **batch**, not "job" or session. While they have their uses, they are often not the best choice vs. a temp table.

Comment: A table variable is a temporary table, not a table created within the tempdb. However, even a @ table uses the tempdb (see https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/15/sql-server-difference-temptable-and-table-variable-temptable-in-memory-a-myth/)

Comment: A table variable is not the same as a temporary table. They are quite different. Also, a global temporary table (`##`) can be accessed within different sessions and if I remember correctly, also by different logins.

Answer (score 71):

Same thing, Just start the table name with `#` or `##`:

```
CREATE TABLE #TemporaryTable          -- Local temporary table - starts with single #
(
    Col1 int,
    Col2 varchar(10)
    ....
);

CREATE TABLE ##GlobalTemporaryTable   -- Global temporary table - note it starts with ##.
(
    Col1 int,
    Col2 varchar(10)
    ....
);
```

Temporary table names start with `#` or `##` - The first is a local temporary table and the last is a global temporary table.

[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/) is one of many articles describing the differences between them.