# TSQL stored procedure result as column in another select

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with input and output parameter.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[pr_MySP]
    @date DATETIME,
    @usd MONEY OUTPUT
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
GO
```

This stored procedure call another stored procedures, so I can't create UDF to do it. And now I need to use this proc result as column in another select. Somethin like this

```
select *, ([dbo].[pr_MySP] result) from ...
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For one SP run:

```
--Declare variables to hold output
DECLARE @usdout MONEY 
--Exec SP and hold value
EXEC pr_MySP @date = null, @usd = @usdout OUT
--Use received value in normal SELECT
select *, @usdout from ...
```

For multirow run, check possible approaches here: [How do I execute a stored procedure once for each row returned by query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886293/how-do-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-once-for-each-row-returned-by-query)

For example, it's possible to use cursor, in each loop insert fresh data in temp table and then join it.

Comment: I need date param from each row of main query

Comment: Please explain what you did editing answer, avoid code only answer

Answer (score 0):

Insert SP result into a temporary table:

```
create table #t (result ...)
declare @date datetime = getdate()
declare @usd money
insert into #t exec [dbo].[pr_MySP] @date = @date, @usd = @usd output
select * from #t
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sp just you have to execute function as  a column

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Function (@Id)
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @param varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT @param as Value
)
GO
```

Then you can write sp as

```
SELECT *,fn_Function(TBL.Id)FROM tbl_Table TBL
```