# Execution of Stored Procedure for every row of table using string variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to execute a stored procedure for every row of a table without using cursor or loop.
Lets say my table dbo.User contains name for following users:

```
create table dbo.test_User  ( 
 Name varchar(50) )

insert into dbo.test_User  
   values  ('Deepanshu'),('IronMan'),('DoctorStrange')
```

I created a stored procedure which will only display the name of users (Although my real stored procedure has to do a lot of stuff)

```
create procedure dbo.usp_TestSP ( @name varchar(50) )
as
BEGIN
    select @name
END
```

Now i want the stored procedure to run for all names like:

```
EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP 'Deepanshu';
EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP 'IronMan';
EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP 'DoctorStrange';
```

I created a string variable @Query which will store the t-sql query i want to execute

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(200);  
select @Query=STUFF(  
                    (select 'dbo.usp_TestSP '''+Name+''';' 
                     from dbo.test_user  
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                    ),1,0,''
                 )  
EXEC @Query
```

When i try to execute this @Query it gives me an error saying:

> Could not find server 'dbo' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

How can i execute the stored procedure for all the names using the string variable @Query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a stored procedure once for each row returned by query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886293/how-do-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-once-for-each-row-returned-by-query)

Comment: Thanks for answering but as i have mentioned, i want to execute this without cursor or loop, using the same logic as displayed above

Comment: You are just missing the EXEC command in your literal. `EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CURSOR` to simulate `FOR-EACH` with stored procedure call:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT *FROM  dbo.tesT_User;

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(50);

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP @name = @name;

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name;
END 

CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ecfebf1537a5e52ccbd03d53a10689e8)**

---

Warning:

If it would be simple function then `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` is a way to go.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test_User tu
OUTER APPLY (SELECT dbo.usp_TestSP(tu.name)) s(a);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06cd43163c9a474400f44e0f86487888)**

---

## EDIT

> i want to execute this without cursor or loop, using the same logic as displayed above

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
   (SELECT string_agg(FORMATMESSAGE('EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP @name=''%s'';', name)
   ,CHAR(13)) AS r FROM dbo.test_User);
PRINT @x;
EXEC(@x);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=92fa15a20158823dd71062b81f3d76cc)**

---

And finally your code:

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(MAX);  
select @Query=STUFF((SELECT 'EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP @name=' +QUOTENAME(Name,'''') 
       + ';' from dbo.test_user
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'');
EXEC(@Query);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13651ebbe4535a16045031906fb38f93)**

What I did:

- using semicolons (`;`) it's very good practice
- changed datatype to `VARCHAR(MAX)`
- added `EXEC` inside SQL
- wrapped `@Query` with `()`

Comment: To handle embedded quotes, I suggest `(select 'EXEC dbo.usp_TestSP ' +QUOTENAME(Name,'''') + ';' from dbo.test_user`