# How to use 2 cursors in Mysql 8 procedure?

Tags: mysql

I need to write Mysql 8 procedure which make union of data from several tables and return some result set returned :

I need some tree structure like :

```
UserPermisionTickets =>
   UserName =>
      TicketUser;
```

I try to make it in a procedure with 2 cursors, but I do not know 1) How to use parameter for the 2nd cursor ?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getUserPermissionTickets $$

create PROCEDURE getUserPermissionTickets(IN permission_id INT, IN user_id INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE userId INT;
    DECLARE userName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE permissionName  VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE userCreatedAt DATETIME;
    DECLARE ticketId  INT;
    DECLARE teamLead tinyint(1);
    DECLARE percent tinyint;

    DEClARE cursorUserPermission
        CURSOR FOR
            SELECT users.id as user_id, users.name as user_name, spt_permissions.name as permission_name, users.created_at as user_created_at
                FROM spt_model_has_roles
                join users, spt_permissions
                where spt_permissions.id = spt_model_has_roles.role_id and
                    users.id = spt_model_has_roles.model_id ;

   DECLARE cursorTicketUser CURSOR FOR SELECT ticket_id, team_lead, percent FROM ticket_user where user_id = :user_id;
  -- 1) Need to get parameters from External loop cursorUserPermission ?

    -- External loop
    OPEN cursorUserPermission;

    userPermissionLoop: LOOP


        FETCH cursorUserPermission INTO userId, userName, permissionName, userCreatedAt;

        -- Internal loop
        OPEN cursorTicketUser;
        TicketUserLoop: LOOP
            FETCH cursorTicketUser INTO ticketId, teamLead, percent;
        END LOOP TicketUserLoop;
        CLOSE cursorTicketUser;


    END LOOP userPermissionLoop;
    CLOSE cursorUserPermission;


END  $$
```

I need to return data which would be data from 1st cursor extended with data from 2nd cursor ?

How can I do it ?

When I try to compile I got error :

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':user_id; 
   -- Need to get parameters from External loop cursorUserPermission ' at line 20
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Nested Cursors in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9699896) (Note, the 2nd cursor is defined inside the loop for the first cursor)

Comment: See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Qrj0yfx) for some ideas.

Comment: Thank you! Can ticket_user be some kind of temporary table? Or only existing table ?

Comment: Yes, `ticket_user` table can be a temporary table, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OkjEQJm9).