# SQL how to create detail table from summary table

Tags: sql, row, summary, unpivot

Now I have a game summary table like this:

[image: Summay Table]

And I want to split the "starttime" and "endtime" by hours and to  convert it into following detailed look:

[image: I need this]

It's kind of similar as Unpivot but not exactly the same. How should I write the sql statement? Thanks a tons!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) If you post what you have tried, people will often be more inclined to help. We don't want to do people's job for them, but we will help if there's something in the SQL that you've tried that you are stuck on.

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, thx!!

Comment: I've tried to use variables to calculate the number of times that one record may need to repeat. But I do not know how to insert the changed record automatically. Also, I need to remove the variable later because SSAS will not allow use of variables as T-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL is:

```sql
SELECT PlayerID
     , generate_series(s.StartTime, s.EndTime - 1) AS StartTimeCol
     , generate_series(s.StartTime + 1, s.EndTime) AS EndTimeCol
FROM summaryTable s
```

In this [Link](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/86/generate_series-for-sql-server-2008) you can see how to add `generate_series` function to *SQL Server 2008*.

View in action [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/20be9/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on SQL Server, you can try the following TSQL block.  It uses a cursor to traverse those rows which have more than 1 hour between start and end times, and iterates through, adding the individual "hours" into a @gamesTable table variable.

Once the cursor is done and has populated records into the @gamesTable variable, a SELECT statement against the original table for those rows which have 1 or less hours between start and end times is unioned to all the rows that were stored into @gamesTable.

```
DECLARE Game_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM summaryTable
    WHERE EndTime - StartTime > 1

OPEN Game_Cursor;
DECLARE @PlayerID char
DECLARE @StartTime int
DECLARE @EndTime int
DECLARE @TempEndTime int
DECLARE @gamesTable TABLE(PlayerID char, StartTime int, EndTime int)

--Fetch the first row
FETCH NEXT FROM Game_Cursor INTO @PlayerID, @StartTime, @EndTime
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        WHILE (@EndTime - @StartTime) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @TempEndTime = @StartTime + 1
            INSERT INTO @gamesTable
                SELECT @PlayerID AS PlayerID, @StartTime AS StartTime, @TempEndTime AS EndTime

            SET @StartTime = @StartTime + 1
        END;

        --Fetch the next row
        FETCH NEXT FROM Game_Cursor INTO @PlayerID, @StartTime, @EndTime
END;

--Rid of the cursor
CLOSE Game_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Game_Cursor;

--Output the results
SELECT * FROM summaryTable WHERE (EndTime - StartTime) <= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM @gamesTable
```

Comment: [Why do people hate SQL cursors so much?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287445/why-do-people-hate-sql-cursors-so-much)

Comment: I think some people don't like cursors because they are at times used in situations where they are not the most efficient solution and waste resources.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use CTE to get the results:

```
;with cte (playerid, starttime, endtime) as 
(
  select playerid, min(starttime) starttime, max(endtime) endtime
  from yourtable
  group by playerid
  union all
  select playerid, starttime + 1, endtime
  from cte
  where starttime < endtime
)
select playerid,
  starttime,
  case 
    when starttime + 1 < endtime
    then starttime + 1
    else endtime
  end endtime
from cte
where starttime != endtime
order by playerid, starttime
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54715/14)