# How can i make a loop in sql table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would like your help to make a stored procedure to update the stock table .
At first I am storing all the bill items in a temporary table and then once save it would deduct the stock from the stock table and it would then store it in Bill_Item table and  Temp_Bill_Item table will be deleted.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the temp table nor cursors are necessary for this:

```
update stock_table
   set qty = qty - bi.qty
from stock_table st
  join bill_items bi
    on bi.item_id = st.item_id
   and bi.itemcode = st.itemcode;
```

This assumes that each item is only present once in the bill_items table. If you can have multiple rows with the same itemid/itemcode you need a slightly different statement:

```
update stock_table
   set qty = qty - bi.total_qty
from stock_table st
  join (select item_id, itemcode, sum(qty) as total_qty 
        from bill_items 
        group by item_id, itemcode
  ) bi
    on bi.item_id = st.item_id
   and bi.itemcode = st.itemcode;
```

(Syntax not tested as you did not post sample data to play with)

Answer (score -1):

For your purposes I would look into using a cursor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Beware that using cursors in SQL has serious performance implications if you're not careful!

[Why do people hate SQL cursors so much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287445/why-do-people-hate-sql-cursors-so-much)