# Update trigger Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to perform an update on a table that has the following update trigger but I am getting the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Here is the trigger...

If the value of photoRatingID is set to NULL then it deletes records from another table

```
IF UPDATE(photoRatingID)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT photoRatingID FROM inserted) IS NULL
        BEGIN
            DELETE mbr_Media_Approval_Primary 
            FROM deleted, mbr_Media_Approval_Primary
            WHERE deleted.mbrID = mbr_Media_Approval_Primary.mbrID
        END
END
```

All tables contain the unique ID 'mbrID'

Comment: Remember that more than one row can be inserted or updated at a time - the trigger needs to do set based operations.

Comment: @StuartLC He can use a cursor and do it in procedural based operations. But i agree that set based operations are the better way of doing things :)

Comment: Yes, you'll find that not many folk like the idea of using [cursors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server) in [Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287445/why-do-people-hate-sql-cursors-so-much), and moreso in a trigger ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT photoRatingID FROM inserted` returns more than one row, as the error message says. Therefore the `IS NULL` comparison cannot work. You can transform your more or less imperative approach to a set based approach like this:

```
IF UPDATE(photoRatingID)
BEGIN
   DELETE map
   FROM mbr_Media_Approval_Primary map
       JOIN deleted d ON d.mbrID=map.mbrID
       JOIN inserted i ON i.mbrID=d.mbrID
   WHERE i.photoRatingID IS NULL
END
```

Comment: Will this perform lookup on every row that is updated (slow performance)? only want to perform lookup when the value is set to NULL

Comment: Depends on the data and the update set. If you worry about performance - you will not beat a declarative query with a cursor, a loop or something else. It's the purpose of the DBMS to choose the best possible strategy to fulfill the query.

Comment: Unfortunately I agree with @Martin K. :) but it would be interesting to see what is the real difference in performance between these two.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of logic you can use a CURSOR example below:

```
IF UPDATE(photoRatingID)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @photoRatingID AS int;  
    DECLARE KURSOR_photoRating CURSOR FOR
        SELECT photoRatingID FROM inserted; 
    OPEN KURSOR_photoRating;    
    FETCH NEXT FROM KURSOR_photoRating INTO @photoRatingID  
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN       
        IF (@photoRatingID IS NULL)
        BEGIN            
            DELETE mbr_Media_Approval_Primary 
            FROM deleted, mbr_Media_Approval_Primary
            WHERE deleted.mbrID = mbr_Media_Approval_Primary.mbrID          
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM KURSOR_photoRating INTO @photoRatingID
    END 
    CLOSE KURSOR_photoRating;    
    DEALLOCATE KURSOR_photoRating;
END
```