# Better way of handling many delete statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a long script for deleting some specific data from a lot (more than 100+) of tables and it looks something like this:

...

```
Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in ('Company1','Company2')
Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in ('Company1','Company2')
Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in ('Company1','Company2')
Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in ('Company1','Company2')
```

...

I want to change this so I don't have to change the variables on every line, I want to be able to set a where statement in the beginning, and that will change all the delete lines

```
declare .....something something
SELECT CompanyID
FROM _Company
WHERE  Company in ('Company1','Company2') -- I want to change this where statement only

Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in (variable)
Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in (variable)
Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in (variable)
Delete from Table_name WHERE Company not in (variable)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** if a single transaction tries to delete more than 5000 rows from any given table. This would put an **exclusive lock** on that table, preventing even `SELECT` from that table, until the transaction is committed (or rolled back). Try to avoid deleting more than 5000 rows at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a **table variable**. Alter column names, datatypes as necessary:

```
DECLARE @idsToKeep TABLE ( CompanyID int );

INSERT @idsToKeep
SELECT CompanyID
FROM _Company
WHERE Company IN ('Company1','Company2'); -- change this one place

DELETE Table_name1 WHERE CompanyID NOT IN ( SELECT CompanyID FROM @idsToKeep ); 
DELETE Table_name2 WHERE CompanyID NOT IN ( SELECT CompanyID FROM @idsToKeep ); 
DELETE Table_name3 WHERE CompanyID NOT IN ( SELECT CompanyID FROM @idsToKeep ); 
-- etc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create a cursor over the select statement and for each resulting entity run the delete statements with proper variables.

Comment: Cursors shouldn't be recommended if there is another way.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287445/why-do-people-hate-sql-cursors-so-much

Comment: I didn't say it was recommended approach. I said "another solution would be", which means that it's an option.